# Advice on connecting meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: Under belly of BMD-2]

Hello all

Is anyone able to advise me on how could I fill in the gap between the outside edges of the two Circles and connect them to the rest of the model

Comment: There is no simple method, you will need to completely rethink and redo whole model.

Comment: No chance of Extruding an edge and loop cutting or anything like that? I don't think I'd have to redo the whole model.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do it, scale out the top of the circle select the vertices from 10 to 2 o'clock then S Y 0 then extrude the straight edge to the adjacent edge of the mesh.

Repeat for the Vertices from 8 to 4 O'clock locations.

Add Loop cuts and joining up the vertices using the magnet tool, select all and press W and click on remove doubles.

Comment: This way you'll not have quad topology and smooth shading and/or adding modifiers will be problematic. Also, could you add some screenshots to your answer?

Comment: @LukeD Aye 2 minutes bud, I'll take a couple screen shots, and the Mesh did need a little clean up nothing too major though.